# print<<EOF in perl- To print $

Tags: perl

Here I want to print the '$' sign. How to do that?

```
 #!/perl/bin/perl
  print <<EOF;
  This sign $ is called dollar
  It's a multiline
  string
  EOF
```

This is giving me result.

```
 This sign  is called dollar
 It's a multiline
 string
```

I want to print $.

Comment: Are you quite sure you did not get the output `This sign  called dollar`?

Comment: May be you're right. But now I am not able to run the code at all. Giving me error can't find string terminator 'EOF'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `EOF` is equivalent to `"EOF"` - the here document is interpolated as if in double quotes. Backslash the dollar sign `\$` or explicitly use single quotes to supress interpolation.

```
print << 'EOF';
...
EOF
```

Comment: When I am using print << 'EOF', it's giving me error that can't find string terminator 'EOF'

Comment: No, now it's giving me that error even if I don't use $ or quotes. I am confused!

Comment: @karate_kid Don't put the quotes around the closing `EOF`. Just around the first. `print <<'EOF' .... EOF`

Comment: Actually now I am running my code only. Still it's giving me error. I'm confused!

Comment: @karate_kid: The closing `EOF` should be followed immediately by end of line, no whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

Running your code with `use warnings` turned on gives me this:

```
Name "main::is" used only once: possible typo at foo.pl line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $is in concatenation (.) or string at foo.pl line 8.
This sign  called dollar
It's a multiline
string
```

As you can see, the `is` is gone from the sentence, and so is the dollar sign. The warnings tell me why: a variable `$is` was found inside the string. Since it was empty, it was replaced by the empty string. Because you did not have warnings turned on, this was done quietly.

The moral is: Always use `use warnings`. Also beneficial in this case would have been `use strict`, as it would have caused the script to fail compilation due to an undeclared variable `$is`.

As for how to fix it, I believe choroba has the solution in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330086/725418).